# C# WPF - How to call a Method everytime the program loops?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's assume that in my MainWindow class there is a bool property that i want my program to close when its true, but in the next loop so that my all elements can update in the GUI window before its closed.

Example:

```
class MainWindow
{
   bool IsTimeToClose {get; set;} 

   MainWindow( .... )
   {
      IsTimeToClose = false;
   }

   //Method that triggers the change of the boolean
   void ChangeImage()
   {
      string source = Get.Source(src); //Example
      ...

      IsTimeToClose = true;

      ...

      Image = source; //Example
   }
}
```

I can't just close the window with Application.Current.Shutdown() or Window.Close() in the end of the method because nothing will be updated in the GUI nor i can create and call mine method.

So is there some trick for that ?

Comment: I know this is not the answer for the question, but it seems to be very wrong design that brought you to such question. Could you elaborate more, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's actually more complicated but my main point is if there is a way to create a method that the application can call everytime so that i can put if statement and check if the application is wanted to be close or not and then closed it if is needed

Comment: The method you're looking for (the loop you mention) can be done with a timer (`System.Timers.Timer`). You subscribe to `Timer.Elapsed` event and there you can check whether the MainWindow should close. Though it is much easier to call `MainWindow.Close` directly from the place where you would set your boolean variable to true.